# Как добраться до узла?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="a">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="name" onclick="func(this)">name1</div>
<div class="submenu">
добрать сюда
</div>
</li>
<li>
...
</li>
<li>
...
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

После нажатия нужно изменить стиль подменю, но я не могу получить элемент.

НА JS

Comment: Покажи код функции func()

Comment: На чистом JS: [10 лучших функций на JavaScript: getElementsByClassName](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass) и там же есть addClass/removeClass.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev function(el) {
        el.style.color = "red";
        el.parentNode.childNodes[1].style.display = "block";
    } Не работает. И выглядит ужасно.

Comment: @Alex Krass класс добавлен с самого начала в html, у него просто стоит свойство display none, и вот это свойство нужно изменить у выбранного елемента

Comment: Замените вторую строку:

document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].style.display = 'block';

Comment: @andrey3 да, но здесь индекс 0, а таких подменю может быть много. Как считаете лучше передавать индекс место this в функцию? Но тогда уж лучше может посчитать вузлы

Comment: el.nextSibling.style.display = "block";

Comment: По просьбе трудящихся спрашиваю: какая библиотека у тебя используется? Можно ли давать решения на jQuery, ExtJS, MooTools, Prototype, KnockoutJS, AngularJS, Zepto, Ember, Backbone, Dojo, YUI?

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev никаких библиотек не используеться. Ответ получен. Всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func(that) {
    var nextElem = elem.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextElem === undefined) {
        nextElem = elem.nextSibling;
        while (nextElem && nextElem.nodeType != 1) {
            nextElem = nextElem.nextSibling;
        }
    } 
    nextElem.style.className += 'style';
}
```

Comment: @lampa а почему вот здесь проверка на undefined и зачем цикл? разве не можно его убрать

Comment: Свойство nextElementSibling - это для IE и этого свойства может не быть если это не IE(undefined), тогда используется nextSibling для остальных браузеров. В свою очередь между тегами могут быть пробелы и прочие особые элементы, которые тоже ловятся nextSibling, поэтому идет цикл до [nodeType](http://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties) равный ELEMENT_NODE = 1;

Comment: `class Name`
`    ^^^`

Comment: C телефона писал. Он, зараза, пробел поставил.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с использованием jQuery:

```
$('.name').on('click', function() {
    $('.submenu').css(/* тут меняете стили */);
});
```

Либо можно задавать стили не напрямую, а устанавливать элементу класс, а стили задавать отдельно:

```
$('.name').on('click', function() {
    $('.submenu').addClass('className');
});
```

Если на странице у вас несколько подменю и при клике на элементе нужно находить соседнее, то просто перемещаетесь по DOM относительно кликнутого элемента:

```
$('.name').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().addClass('className');
});
```

Как видите, все очень просто и кроссбраузерно.

И не нужно устанавливать обработчик в разметке, почитайте про ненавязчивый JavaScript.

Comment: Просто для интереса - а с чего вы взяли, что автору подойдет jquery?

Comment: А почему он должен не подойти? Код решает задачу. К тому же это намного проще и удобней, чем писать велосипеды на голом JS.

Comment: И конечно было бы правильней добавить элементу класс с помощью метода .addClass(), а стили устанавливать отдельно.

Comment: Может у него высоконагруженный ресурс, в котором каждый байт на счету, а вы ему лишние килобиты суете. Или уже есть несколько других библиотек, которые конфликтуют с JQuery. Конечно надумано, но вообще стоит пояснять, что используется сторонняя либа.

Comment: jQuery тоже написан на чистом JS :) Да и зачем такой геморрой, когда проще получить требуемую версию jQuery с CDN Google? На скорости работы сайта это практически не скажется.

Comment: @andreyqin а как на чистом javascript?

Comment: @andreyqin, а если это закрытая ERP-система? Какой-нибудь IBM Notes к примеру, который использует Java машину и может на слабых серверах выдавать низкую скорость и требуется оптимизация всего и вся, при этом ввиду закрытости никакого доступа к гугл репозиториям нет. В общем-то это не важно... просто хочу сказать, что стоит указывать в ответе про использование сторонней библиотеки.

Comment: @Alex Krass закрытая ERP система может себе позволить jquery потому что скорее всего в интрасети работает. И обычно там такой шлак в коде, что jquery ничего не только не испортит, но и не улучшит.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, но чисто гипотетически я же могу себе представить такие ситуации. Ну или давайте реальный пример - сказали написать на чистом JS без всяких сторонних библиотек и никак иначе. Зачем? Задание от преподавателя или желание работодателя проверить навыки претендента.

Comment: >>> Задание от преподавателя или желание работодателя проверить навыки претендента

@Alex Krass, это повод к удалению вопроса. Без обид. Такие правила.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#a').on('click', '.name', function() {
$('.submenu').addClass('new_style'); });
```

.new_style {
~ код стиля
}